# How to make formula look professional

Tags: formatting, equations

I write the formulae using belowing latex, however, it looks some kind of messy especially the Equation 1. Any suggestions on how to make it professional?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, proof} % mathabx,
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{utilityv}
\begin{array}{rcl}
U(a)& =& w_1*\frac{Ur_{Max}(s)-a.r}{Ur_{Max}(s)-Ur_{Min}(s)}\\
&+& w_2*\frac{A{a} * AvgA(s')-Ua_{Min}(s)}{Ua_{Max}(s)-Ua_{Min}(s)}\\
&+& w_3*\frac{Uc_{Max}(s)-(C{a}+AvgC(s'))}{Uc_{Max}(s)-Uc_{Min}(s)}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}\label{utilityruti}
\begin{array}{rcl}
Ur_{Max}(s)& = &\max\limits_{a\in MAct(s)}(a.r)\\
Ur_{Min}(s) &=& \min\limits_{a\in MAct(s)}(a.r)\\
Ua_{Max}(s)& = &\max\limits_{a\in MAct(s)}(A(a) * AvgA(s'))\\
Ua_{Min}(s) &=& \min\limits_{a\in MAct(s)}(A(a) * AvgA(s'))\\
Uc_{Max}(s) &=& \max\limits_{a\in MAct(s)}(C(a)+AvgC(s'))\\
Uc_{Min} (s) &=& \min\limits_{a\in MAct(s)}(C{a}+AvgC(s'))

\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, you need some [consistency](http://goo.gl/792Wc). Are `A`, `C` and `U` functions (taking an argument)? What about `MAct`? Also, don't use the `minimal` document class, since it does not define the appropriate lengths (causing your crunched horizontal spacing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a couple of options

[image: screenshot]

In this option I

- replaced `*` with `\cdot`
- introduced `\DeclareMathOperator` for `Avg` and `Mact`, changing it to `\mathcal{M}`
- made a new command for `Max`, and `Min`
- changed the aligned environments to `aligned` instead of `array`

Another option:

[image: screenshot]

I took more liberties in this option, and modified your notation quite a lot- personally I find `U^{(r)}` a lot easier to read than `Ur`, but that's just my opinion.

Here's the complete code, see what you think!

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Avg}{Avg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mact}{\mathcal{M}}
\newcommand{\Max}{\textnormal{Max}}
\newcommand{\Min}{\textnormal{Min}}
\begin{document}

\section*{Option 1}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        U(a) & = w_1\cdot\frac{Ur_{\Max}(s)-a.r}{Ur_{\Max}(s)-Ur_{\Min}(s)}                                  \\
             & \phantom{ {}=}+ w_2\cdot\frac{A(a) \cdot \Avg(A(s'))-Ua_{\Min}(s)}{Ua_{\Max}(s)-Ua_{\Min}(s)} \\
             & \phantom{ {}=}+ w_3\cdot\frac{Uc_{\Max}(s)-(C(a)+\Avg(C(s')))}{Uc_{\Max}(s)-Uc_{\Min}(s)}     
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        Ur_{\Max}(s)  & = \max_{a\in \Mact(s)}(a.r)                    \\
        Ur_{\Min}(s)  & = \min_{a\in \Mact(s)}(a.r)                    \\
        Ua_{\Max}(s)  & = \max_{a\in \Mact(s)}(A(a) \cdot \Avg(A(s'))) \\
        Ua_{\Min}(s)  & = \min_{a\in \Mact(s)}(A(a) \cdot \Avg(A(s'))) \\
        Uc_{\Max}(s)  & = \max_{a\in \Mact(s)}(C(a)+\Avg(C(s')))       \\
        Uc_{\Min} (s) & = \min_{a\in \Mact(s)}(C(a)+\Avg(C(s')))       
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\section*{Option 2}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        U(a) & = w_1\cdot\frac{U^{(r)}_{\Max}(s)-a.r}{U^{(r)}_{\Max}(s)-U^{(r)}_{\Min}(s)}                                  \\
             & \phantom{ {}=}+ w_2\cdot\frac{A(a) \cdot \Avg(A(s'))-U^{(a)}_{\Min}(s)}{U^{(a)}_{\Max}(s)-U^{(a)}_{\Min}(s)} \\
             & \phantom{ {}=}+ w_3\cdot\frac{U^{(c)}_{\Max}(s)-(C(a)+\Avg(C(s')))}{U^{(c)}_{\Max}(s)-U^{(c)}_{\Min}(s)}     
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        U^{(r)}_{\Max}(s)  & = \max_{a\in \Mact(s)}(a.r)                    \\
        U^{(r)}_{\Min}(s)  & = \min_{a\in \Mact(s)}(a.r)                    \\
        U^{(a)}_{\Max}(s)  & = \max_{a\in \Mact(s)}(A(a) \cdot \Avg(A(s'))) \\
        U^{(a)}_{\Min}(s)  & = \min_{a\in \Mact(s)}(A(a) \cdot \Avg(A(s'))) \\
        U^{(c)}_{\Max}(s)  & = \max_{a\in \Mact(s)}(C(a)+\Avg(C(s')))       \\
        U^{(c)}_{\Min} (s) & = \min_{a\in \Mact(s)}(C(a)+\Avg(C(s')))       
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\limits`? By default, `aligned` uses `\displaystyle`, so it's not necessary. And, while `\Avg` is a math operator, `\Max` and `\Min` aren't, so their definition should be like `\newcommand{\Max}{\textnormal{Max}}`. Finally, `\MAct` should definitely be an operator (or `\mathit` should be used).

Comment: @egreg thanks for the feedback- I have updated